# How to connect to Azure Vault from Microsoft Flow?

Tags: azure, power-automate

I am trying to connect to my Azure Vault from Microsoft Power Automate - Flow.

[image: Power Automate Flow]

My Vault has following access policy -
[image: Azure Vault]

Now, I want my Microsoft Flow to access this vault and fetch the secrets sucessfully. What IP Address should I add to the Vault Firewall? Is there a way I can get the IP address being used for this Flow and then I can add that IP address in the vault firewall as exception.

I tried few things, but I am getting this error -

```
{
  "status": 403,
  "message": "Operation against key vault 'https://something.vault.azure.net/' failed as connector IP address is not authorized to call the vault. If you have configured firewall on the vault, please make sure the logic app IP addresses are allowed. Please see https://aka.ms/connectors-ip-addresses",
  "error": {
    "message": "Operation against key vault 'https://something.vault.azure.net/' failed as connector IP address is not authorized to call the vault. If you have configured firewall on the vault, please make sure the logic app IP addresses are allowed. Please see https://aka.ms/connectors-ip-addresses"
  },
  "source": "keyvault-cus.azconn-cus-001.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the error?  Does that not help?  Alternatively ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/common/outbound-ip-addresses#power-platform

Comment: I cannot get the IP Address or the region being used in my Flow. I am using MS Flow, not Logic Apps.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results and followed below process:

Firstly, created a key vault as same as your settings:

[image]

Then in Flow I got similar error as below:

[image]

Then I opened my properties section of flow(Or logic app) and found connector Ip addresses:

[image]

Then inside my key vault added the Ip addresses as below:

[image]

Each ip address one line then again add then paste the add then paste till last ip address as shown in above pic. Then apply.

Then I run my Logic app and I got Secrets as below:
[image]

[image]

If you follow above process, you will get your secrets as i have got mine.

**OR:**
Just change your settings as below to allow all ip addresses and it works fine too.

[image]

If you can't find ip addresses of your flow, then use [Managed connectors outbound IP addresses | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/common/outbound-ip-addresses#power-platform) to get ip addresses of your connector flow region.
I guess this should clear all your doubts.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Flow, not Logic app. Cannot find the properties section or IP address for Microsoft Flow. Also, I cannot get the region in which the Flow is running.

Comment: [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/regions-overview#how-can-i-find-out-the-region-where-my-flow-is-deployed) link shows how to find region of powerautomate . [Reference2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/power-platform/power-automate/check-if-gateway-is-the-right-region#verifying-issue). From here you will get to the region then add the ip addresses from the link i have given in answer.

Comment: Already checked this, but I do not have any Environments listed at the link - https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com/environments

Comment: Seems like I do not have access to Environment, but I got the IP address of my Flow by following [this](https://powernimbus.com/2021/04/whats-the-ip-of-my-flow/). Added all the IP Addresses, still no luck.

Comment: Which Location is your flow located? I can give which IP's to add if i know the  region.

Comment: You need to get The IP address of Connectors(Outgoing) not Flows